# About form $ax^2+bx+c$ always representing a perfect square number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I found that if $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c(a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z},a\neq0)$ always form a pefect square number for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$,Then there must exists $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that  $f(x)=(sx+t)^2$,but I cannot prove it.

Since $f(0)=c$ is a pefect square,there exists $t^2=c$. Then consider any prime $p|t$,$f(p)=ap^2+bp+t^2=n^2$,so $p|n$,$p^2|n^2$.Because $p^2|t^2$,there must be $p|b$ for all $p|t$,so $t|b$,It should be $t|b$ since I hope b=2st,but I get stuck here.
What's more ,by consider $b=\frac{f(1)-f(-1)}{2}$ and perfect square module 4,I can prove b is a even number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a special case of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem, as noted explicitly
in
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem)'s 
article on that theorem.  Specializing the proof yields the following
argument, for which it is enough to assume that $f(x)$ takes square values
for a few sufficiently large consecutive integer values of $x$.

For integers $n$, let $g_n = \sqrt{f(n)}$.
By hypothesis each $g_n$ is an integer.
On the other hand, there is some constant $C$ such that 
the second finite difference $d_n := g_{n+2} - 2 g_{n+1} + g_n$ 
satisfies $|d_n| < C/n$ for large $n$.  (This can be seen in several ways,
e.g. by applying Rolle's theorem twice, or by expanding
$d_n$ in a Laurent series about $n = \infty$.)  Since $d_n$ is an integer,
it follows that $d_n = 0$ for large $n$, say $n>N_0$.
But this means that $g_n$ is eventually linear: there exist integers $A,B$
such that $g_n = An+B$ for all $n > N_0$.  Then $f(n) = (An+B)^2$ for all
$n > N_0$, which makes $f(x) = (Ax+B)^2$ identically, **QED**.

Comment: Thank you professor, and the solution is quite advanced for a K-12 math teacher. Wish could be able to digest the proof instantly.

Comment: Basically all I'm saying is that for large $n$ we have
$g_n = a^{1/2} n + a^{-1/2} b/2 + {}$ lower order terms, so
if we write $e(n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$ then $e(n) = a^{1/2} + {}$ lower order, 
and repeating the procedure once more we find that $e(n+1) - e(n) \to 0$
as $n \to \infty$.  But $e(n+1) - e(n) = g_n$ which is an integer,
so eventually all $g_n$ are zero, so all $e(n)$ are equal $-$ say $e(n) = A$
$-$ and then by induction $g_n = An+B$.

Comment: Thank you professor. I remembered you in the Putnam days at Harvard back in the nineties or earlier than that, and your unique approach to math is amazing .

Comment: Thanks.  My "Putnam days" were 1982-85, and alas I did not get to spend them
at Harvard, but I've been here since then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and introduction of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem.But I don't understand how to "applying Rolle's theorem twice" to get$d_n<C/n$(another approach by Laurent expanding is easier to me),Could you give a more detailed explain for this?

Comment: More precisely I should have written "mean value theorem" instead of 
"Rolle's theorem".  The MVT says $g_{n+1} - g_n$ is the value at some
$x_n \in (n,n+1)$ of the derivative of $\sqrt{f(n)}$.  Replacing $n$ by $n+1$
and subtracting, we find that $d_n$ is $x_{n+1} - x_n$ time the value 
somewhere in $(n,n+2)$ of the second derivative.  But that second derivative
is $O(1/n)$ for large $n$, and $x_{n+1} - x_n < 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the further explaination ,now I totally understand the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions of the equation:

$$ax^2-by^2+cx-dy+q=0$$

you can record if the root of the whole: $k=\sqrt{(c-d)^2-4q(a-b)}$

Then using the solutions of the equation Pell: $p^2-abs^2=\pm1$

Then the formula of the solution, you can write:

$$x=\frac{\pm1}{2(a-b)}(((d-c)\pm{k})p^2+2(bk\mp(bc-ad))ps+b(a(d+c)-2bc\pm{ak})s^2)$$

$$y=\frac{\pm1}{2(a-b)}(((d-c)\pm{k})p^2+2(ak\mp(bc-ad))ps-a(b(d+c)-2ad\mp{bk})s^2)$$

If the root is a need to find out if this is equivalent to the quadratic form in which the root of the whole. This is usually accomplished this replacement: $x$ in such number $x+ty$

Forgot to say. The characters inside the brackets do not depend on the sign of the Pell equation.

It depends only before $\pm{1}$